# How to get uuid of mobile (iOS & android) permanently in react native

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working react native project.
I'd like to know how to get uuid of mobile and keep it on firestore.
I've tried to do it using anonymous uuid in firestore. However, this one wasn't solution cause if an user remove an app and re-install the app, then uuid is changed.
So, I need to keep immutable uuid.

If you have any of idea, please let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think that keeping the UUID the same after the user has removed the app and reinstalled is impossible. From [ios docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor): "The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. ", and from [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID): "The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device or if an APK signing key changes".

Comment: Hmm... so it's impossible.
Is there no way to solve this problem? I don't want to bother that users make sign up. :(

Comment: If you have the user sign up into the app - then you should keep their token in the device memory.